# Google Admin SDK in PHP

Tags: php, json, google-api, google-apps, google-admin-sdk

I am using the following code to retrieve the list of users associated with my google apps account. 
There is no problem with authentication but when the redirection made this error is appearing.

index.php

```
<?php
require_once 'test_user/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'test_user/src/contrib/Google_PlusService.php';
require_once 'test_user/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php';
require_once 'test_user/src/contrib/Google_DirectoryService.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("ApplicationName");

//*********** Replace with Your API Credentials **************
$client->setClientId('****');
$client->setClientSecret('****');
$client->setRedirectUri('****');
$client->setDeveloperKey('****');
//************************************************************


$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly'));
$plus = new Google_PlusService($client);
$oauth2 = new Google_Oauth2Service($client); // Call the OAuth2 class for get email address
$adminService = new Google_DirectoryService($client); // Call directory API

if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate();
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
}

if ($client->getAccessToken())
{
  $user = $oauth2->userinfo->get();
  $me = $plus->people->get('me');
  $email = filter_var($user['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); // get the USER EMAIL ADDRESS using OAuth2

  $optParams = array('maxResults' => 100);
  $activities = $plus->activities->listActivities('me', 'public', $optParams);
  //$users = $adminService->users->get($email);

  $list_users = $adminService->users->listUsers();
  print '<h2>Response Result:</h2><pre>' . print_r($list_users, true) . '</pre>';
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}
else
{
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  header("location:$authUrl");
}
?>
```

error i'm getting:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_ServiceException' with message 'Error calling
GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?
key=AIzaSyBp0yBFCCosu113tbNbw7yAIjIt1ndFFIs: (400) Bad Request' in 
/var/www/vhosts/vx44.com/httpdocs/test_user/src/io/Google_REST.php:66 Stack trace: #0 
/var/www/vhosts/vx44.com/httpdocs/test_user/src/io/Google_REST.php(36): 
Google_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_HttpRequest)) #1 
/var/www/vhosts/vx44.com/httpdocs/test_user/src/service/Google_ServiceResource.php(186):     
Google_REST::execute(Object(Google_HttpRequest)) #2 
/var/www/vhosts/vx44.com/httpdocs/test_user/src/contrib/Google_DirectoryService.php(695):     
Google_ServiceResource->__call('list', Array) #3         
/var/www/vhosts/vx44.com/httpdocs/test_user/test_user.php(52): 
Google_UsersServiceResource->listUsers('nelson302.com') #4 {main} thrown in/var/www/vhosts/vx44.com/httpdocs/test_user/src/io/Google_REST.php on line 66
```

Note that i've enabled Admin SDK on Google APIs Console.

What am i doing wrong here? thank you for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
$list_users = $adminService->users->listUsers();
```

with:

```
$adminOptParams = array('customer' => 'my_customer');
$list_users = $adminService->users->listUsers($adminOptParams);
```

this is explained in the [Admin SDK Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_all_users).